# Elasticsearch synonym and boost by category

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue using elasticsearch wasting a lot of time in this issue may be you can help me.

I have and index with a lot of products and I set a boost based on some categories with this search:

```
{ 
  "from": 1,
  "size": 10
  "query": {
      "bool": {
           'must': {
                'match': {
                    'NAME': {
                         "query": "tv",
                         "operator": "and"
                    }
                },
           },
           "should": { 
                "query_string": {
                    "query": 'category: 23',
                    "boost": 2
                }
           }
       }
}
```

This work fine, and the scoring of the results has been changed for these category.

Now we wanna introduce the synonyms for the search and we set the synoynyms as a analyzer in elasticsearch using this method:

```
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
         "synonym": {
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "synonym_filter"]
         }
    },
    "filter": {
        "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "language": "spanish",
            "synonyms": [
                "tv, television, tdt"
             ]
        }
    }
}
```

We change the query to use the new analyzer and this work fine:

```
{
    "from": 1,
    "size": 10
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': {
                'match': {
                    'NAME': {
                        "query": "television",
                        "operator": "and",
                        "analyzer": "synonym"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when we try to apply boost to this query the result doesnt vary

```
{
    "from": 1,
    "size": 10
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': {
                'match': {
                    'NAME': {
                        "query": "television",
                        "operator": "and",
                        "analyzer" => "synonym"
                    }
                 },
             },
             "should": { 
                 "query_string": {
                     "query": 'category: 23',
                     "boost" => 2
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Regards.

Comment: Are you using a custom analyzer?

Answer (score 0):

Index `Boost`-ing has been deprecated in the new version of [5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html?class=admon_content) where as `field mapping boost` is available. I guess you're aware of it.

> index time boost is deprecated.

If it's a field level of boosting while indexing, shouldn't your query be like:

```
"should": { 
              "query_string": {
                   "query": 'category: 23',
                   "boost": 2
               }
          }
```

If that's not the case, should be with the `analyzer` then. Shouldn't you be having the `analysis` within the `settings` tag:

```
PUT /index
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[could be helpful](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html).

Comment: Hi, I think you are wrong, the index boosting has been changed to query boosting in elasticsearch 5.0:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/index-boost.html

In fact, the operation of the boost without synonyms is correct and 100% satisfactory

On the other hand, in elastic 5 the update of parameters of the index is done without the settings, as it specifies the official documentation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

Comment: @JuanjoAguilellaMarés oops thanks :) I've mis-written the answer. Did including your analysis within the settings work which I've mentioned in the latter part of my answer?

Comment: In the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) which you provided, the PUT url (localhost:9200/myindex/_settings) should contain the settings, isn't it? If you're doing that way then it should be fine.

Comment: @JuanjoAguilellaMarés any positive changes??

Comment: Hi @Kulasar I send the settings ussing the PUT method to /_settings. Features work well separately, but I want to work together. No positive changes

Comment: I wanna search "tv" and the I found products with "TV" and "television" expressions and boosted first that I have in category 23.